# What does Mongoose's Model.find() do if it doesn't find a document?

Tags: mongoose

I'm struggling to find this answer in the Mongoose documentation, but I'm wondering if I'm using a callback with the `(err, doc) => {}` pattern, and `find()` doesn't find a document, will the `doc` argument of the callback be null, or will there be an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be an ***empty array***, I think the best way to find out is trying, just run the code and `console.log()` result

Comment: Thanks so much Vahe! And yes not sure why I didn't just do that on my own!